# multi layer perceptron tested in raw data vs edited data

Tags: neural-networks

I have a dataset of 113x113 gray images divided into 3 classes where I have applied different multi layer neural network classification algorithms taking as features the total of pixels 113x113=12769 features. Although I haven't achieved more than 65% os success when testing it on the testing data.

However, when I test a new neural network but taking now into account just only 9 new features that are calculated from the raw data such as the mean of the pixels, the standard deviation,... so in this case I get to achieve 74%.

How can I get better results? Does this make sense? Are not the neural networks supposed to be tested only in raw data from images so as to find out patterns?

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(12769,),activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(78,activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))   
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

vs

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(9,),activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(12,activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))    
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What architecture is your neural network? Classifying on raw pixels is hard, even for greyscale images of that size. If you're not using a Convolutional neural network or other architecture designed for image classification, the task might be too difficult for your network. Learning from fewer features is a lot easier and faster. You may need to train longer, with different hyperparameters, architecture, etc. to yield benefits of pixel-based classification.